# How to fix each column in Table?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table

I tried to read the source code in Wordpress at following picture.

I have no idea how they could fix each column HTML/CSS, no clue what they use.

When you turn to other page, the columns are still at the same position.

But when I try pagination/table library in CodeIgniter by turning to other page, the table is flexible and is dependent on the information in the cell.

Image here:

[image]

Comment: Is this about table cell widths (and behaviour)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use divs with width

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div style="width: 200px;">
        test...
        </div></td>
        <td><div style="width: 600px;">
        test...
        </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `width` attribute is specified in the CSS:

```
.fixed .column-response, 
.fixed .column-author, 
.fixed .column-categories, 
.fixed .column-tags, 
.fixed .column-rel, 
.fixed .column-role {
    width: 15%;
}
```

And similarly, the `table` element is fixed width:

```
table.fixed {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/table-layout) CSS property, e.g.:

```
#mytable
{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```